# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Field add default values

Tags: c#, tfs

Try to add defaults value to defects.

```
var x = Defect.Validate();
if (x.Count != 0)
{
foreach (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Field item in x)
{
Defect[item.Name] = item.AllowedValues.Count==0?"test": item.AllowedValues[0];
}
}
```

Adding this do'sent help! is another way to do.

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use?

Comment: Is the code sample below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/add?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) below to add a field to a work item type:

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/fields?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

Here are some code samples to help you:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTrackingProcess/ProcessesSample.cs#L426

```
       public ProcessWorkItemTypeField Field_AddFieldToWorkItemType()
        {
            ProcessWorkItemTypeField processWorkItemTypeField = null;
            System.Guid processId = Context.GetValue<Guid>("$processId");

            VssConnection connection = Context.Connection;
            WorkItemTrackingProcessHttpClient client = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingProcessHttpClient>();

            //get the list of fields on the work item item
            Console.Write("Loading list of fields on the work item and checking to see if field '{0}' already exists...", _fieldRefName);

            List<ProcessWorkItemTypeField> list = client.GetAllWorkItemTypeFieldsAsync(processId, _witRefName).Result;

            //check to see if the field already exists on the work item
            processWorkItemTypeField = list.Find(x => x.ReferenceName == _fieldRefName);

            //field is already on the work item, so just return it
            if (processWorkItemTypeField != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("field found");
                return processWorkItemTypeField;
            }
            else
            {
                //the field is not on the work item, so we best add it
                Console.WriteLine("field not found");
                Console.Write("Adding field to work item...");

                AddProcessWorkItemTypeFieldRequest fieldRequest = new AddProcessWorkItemTypeFieldRequest()
                {
                    AllowGroups = false,
                    DefaultValue = String.Empty,
                    ReadOnly = false,
                    ReferenceName = _fieldRefName,
                    Required = false
                };

                processWorkItemTypeField = client.AddFieldToWorkItemTypeAsync(fieldRequest, processId, _witRefName).Result;

                Console.WriteLine("done");

                return processWorkItemTypeField;
            }
        }
```